# Does a magic circle protect a creature partially inside the area of effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, area-of-effect

If a creature is partially inside a *magic circle against evil*'s area of effect when it is cast or is simply too big to fit inside the zone, does the protection work?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it does

This is implied by the second effect of [Magic Circle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-circle-against-evil/), when used as a trap:

> If a creature too large to fit into the spell’s area is the subject of the spell, the spell acts as a normal protection from evil spell for that creature only.

When a creature is partially inside the area of a spell, the creature is affected normally by that spell (for instance, a *Fireball*), and the effect of *Magic Circle*'s protection effect doesn't seem to be an exception to this. This ruling can be seen [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/):

> When determining whether a given creature is within the area of a spell, **count out the distance from the point of origin in squares** just as you do when moving a character or when determining the range for a ranged attack. The only difference is that instead of counting from the center of one square to the center of the next, you count from intersection to intersection.
>
> You can count diagonally across a square, but remember that every second diagonal counts as 2 squares of distance. **If the far edge of a square is within the spell’s area, anything within that square is within the spell’s area**. If the spell’s area only touches the near edge of a square, however, anything within that square is unaffected by the spell.

The secondary effect, however, requires for the outsider to be completely inside the spell's area, otherwise it cannot be trapped.

Comment: Huh. So, for example, a creature even partially in the dark is, essentially, completely in the dark?

Comment: @HeyICanChan dark as in created by a darkness spell? No. Because it doesn't affect creatures, it affects the illumination level in the area. Creatures inside the area cannot see whats inside the area, but they see whats outside normally, should they be able to pierce the spell effect (say, with darkvision).

Answer (score -1):

The typical 'at least half' rule of thumb usually covers things like this - it isn't a catch all [things with 1ft by # ft lines for example which I don't think exist in pathfinder but if they did the 'at least half of a square' wouldn't really work for such lines] So if at least half a square is affected by something normally the whole square is affected - if at least half of a creature is affected by something the whole creature is affected.

Also keep in mind that in this case you would need MORE then half the squares of anything bigger than medium for a circle - because you can mathematically see that not half the creature is in the circle unless at least one more square then half the creature normally takes up is actually inside the circle [although if you go by the rule of thumb for squares then extrapolate from there then you can have a creature be exactly half affected by the circle and therefor still be affected by it]

Comment: Could you reference the source of "at least half"?

Comment: The phrase 'rule of thumb' meant that there's no source for it - it's just a case where that is a huge help if you don't know exactly what works for when and you don't want to break up the game trying to find out. Again it doesn't catch everything but it simplifies a lot of AOE 'does this thing get effected by x' questions - especially when you start throwing 60 foot lines at angles of like 20 degrees